# Node not getting installed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

nvm version -> 0.29.0.
Then installed libkrb5-dev and npm.
npm --version -> 1.3.10

nodejs -v is showing v0.10.25, which is very old in /usr/bin
But 'node' is not installed.

Need to install Node 4.
Being new to node, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `whereis node` tell you Ubuntu is looking for Node?

I'm not sure if this exists on Ubuntu, but on OS X there's a file called `/etc/paths` which sets the precedence of where binaries are loaded from.

I'm going to guess that you've installed Node to `/usr/local/bin` so it might be a case of moving this to the top of that file and restarting.

Comment: which node, whereis node gives no answer.Have checked the path, there is no node file in any location /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:  So basically npm is not installing node. Then how do I install it?

Comment: Node should be installing npm, not the other way around. I personally use `nvm` (from homebrew) to install node, but there's another package called `n` too.

Comment: I had missed 'nvm use node_version'. Now node -v gives v4.2.2 Learning :

Comment: I had missed 'nvm use node_version'. Now node -v gives v4.2.2 Steps learnt: 1) Install nvm 2) install node via nvm ... This also installs npm.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)